# Transparent spritesheet has black background

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a game using Python and Pygame. I created a sprite sheet for one of the enemies and got my code for it working. The problem is that the image appears to have a black background even though it is a transparent image. The code for it is this:

```
    enemySheet = pygame.image.load("resources/Alien.png").convert_alpha()
    transColor = (255,255,255)
    cells = []
    for n in range(3):
        width, height=(36,32)
        rect = pygame.Rect(n * width, 0, width, height)
        image = pygame.Surface(rect.size).convert_alpha()
        image.blit(enemySheet, (0,0), rect)
        cells.append(image)

    enemyImg = cells[0]
    enemyImg.set_colorkey(transColor)
    enemy = enemyImg.get_rect()
    enemy.center = (216,216)
```

I have already tried a few things but nothing has worked. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New surfaces are filled with black by default. If you want to make it transparent you can either add a fourth number to the `transColor` (the alpha value) and then fill the `image`,

```
transColor = (255,255,255,0)

    # In the for loop.
    image = pygame.Surface(rect.size).convert_alpha()
    image.fill(transColor)
```

or just pass the `pygame.SRCALPHA` flag:

```
image = pygame.Surface(rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
```

A nicer solution would be to use [`pygame.Surface.subsurface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) to cut the sheet:

```
for n in range(3):
    width, height = (36, 32)
    rect = pygame.Rect(n * width, 0, width, height)
    image = enemySheet.subsurface(rect)
    cells.append(image)
```