# How to remove black background from sprite in sprite sheet in pygame

Tags: python, sprite

I am trying to remove the black background from this sprite taken from a sprite sheet.  As you'll see in the following is the code and suggested by this post ([Transparent spritesheet has black background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119295/transparent-spritesheet-has-black-background)),  I've tried to use the pygame.SRCALPHA flag but this does not seem to work.  I've even tried to use the same sprite sheet after converting it with a transparent background and I get the same black border around the Mario sprite.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

def imgcolorkey(image, colorkey):
    if colorkey is not None:
        if colorkey is -1:
            colorkey = image.get_at((0, 0))
        image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)
    return image

class SpriteSheet(object):
    sprite_sheet = None
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        #self.sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load(file_name).convert()
        self.sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load(file_name,pygame.SRCALPHA)
    #self.sheet = load_image(filename)

    def imgat(self, rect, colorkey = None):
        rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
        #image = pygame.Surface(rect.size).convert()
        #image = pygame.Surface(rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA ).convert()
        image = pygame.Surface(rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
        #image.fill(transColor)
        image.blit(self.sprite_sheet, (0, 0), rect)
        return imgcolorkey(image, colorkey)

    def imgsat(self, rects, colorkey = None):
        imgs = []
        for rect in rects:
            imgs.append(self.imgat(rect, colorkey))
        return imgs
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

I was not sending the colorkey argument of -1 when building the image in my main class.

I changed:

```
mario_image = SPRITE_SHEET.imgsat(MARIO_COORD)
```

to:

```
images = SPRITE_SHEET.imgsat(MARIO_COORD,-1)
```